# preventDefault does not behave equal in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery preventDefault on a keydown event: http://jsbin.com/ixaqok/edit#javascript,html
When running the example code in Firefox and Opera the keypress event still is fired, but in Chrome, IE8 and Safari it's not.

Why?
Is preventDefault not supposed to work the same in all browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that unlike other browsers, Opera only allows you to suppress the default behaviour of keystrokes in the `keypress` event, not the `keydown` event. Therefore the solution is to use the `keypress` event instead.

For more details, use what I consider the definitive page on the mess that is browser key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html. Suppressing default key behaviour is section 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Opera has problem with recognizing and resolving keydown (and some other key releated funcitons)

see:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ (in discussion)

Comment: Not really. Opera has no problem with firing key events with correct key codes. The problem is in suppressing default key behaviour. See my answer.